# Falha ao arquivar projeto Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin-forms

Seguinte, estou terminando meu projeto e como ultimo passo estou tentando "arquivar" meu projeto android, porem ao tentar arquiva-lo ele gera o seguinte erro:

```
    Erro        Falha inesperada da tarefa "LinkAssemblies".
Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Pages.BaseDataSource/<Initialize>d__22::MoveNext()' in assembly: 'Xamarin.Forms.Pages.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Log::Warning(System.String,System.String)
   em Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
   em Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
   em Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
   em Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   em Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   em Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exceções internas ---
   em Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   em Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessEntireQueue()
   em Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   em Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   em Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   em MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
   em Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   em Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   em Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   em Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() AppRDVAUX.Android   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets   1748
```

Após muita procura verifiquei que esse erro esta relacionado a uma opção marcada no Android.Manifest chamada de Linker(vinculação), nela voce tem a opção de "compactar" seu aplicativo de forma ao não ficar muito grande. Sem essa opção marcada o meu projeto gera o apk, porem fica muito grande(70mb). ***Então resumindo, alguem sabe como fazer para que essa opção de vinculação funcione ou se tem algum outro meio de fazer o apk gerado ficar menor?*** Desde já agradeço a quem puder responder.

Answer (score 2):

O mecanismo do [**Linker**](https://github.com/mono/linker) não é baseado em uma *compactação*, mas sim em remoção de recursos não utilizados (basicamente métodos e classes) no seu aplicativo. É assim que ele reduz o tamanho do app - *"capando"* as bibliotecas referenciadas para manter somente o que for utilizado.

A questão é que, para isso, o linker identifica o que está ou não sendo utilizado através de uma análise estática, e algumas vezes ele pode remover métodos que estão sendo utilizados em tempo de execução (como métodoso invocados via reflexão, por exemplo).

Em uma tradução livre, a [documentação da microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker#linker-behavior) diz que

> Aplicações `Xamarin.Android` usam o *linker* para reduzir o tamanho do aplicativo. O linker aplica uma análise estátiva da sua aplicação para determinar que bibliotecas, tipos e membros estão sendo de fato utilizados. Ele se comporta como um *garbage collector*, buscando recursivamente por bibliotecas, tipos e membro que são referenciados até determinar o escopo de utilização da biblioteca. A partir daí, tudo foroa desse escopo é *descartado*.

Confesso que usar o Linker total não é uma tarefa trivial quando já se tem um projeto construido: é um processo lento identificar e corrigir as remoções indevidas. Esse assunto, inclusive, está sendo ministrado como um tópico avançado na [Maratona Xamarin](https://cursos.bsgrupo.com/courses/course-v1:Microsoft+XMRBR101+2018_T1/about) que está em curso.

Em geral, o pessoal indica usar o a opção intermédiaria (passar o Linker nas bibliotecas do SDK somente) e desde o início do projeto, pois assim fica mais fácil identificar caso algo que não devia tenha diso removido . Isso já dá uma boa reduzida no tamanho do app.

### Como aplicar o linker no projeto

Você pode começar entendendo o [comportamento do Linker](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker#linker-behavior), usando a opção "Bibliotecas do SDK" inicialmente e ir fazendo as configurações dos elementos que são utilizados em *tempo de execução* após identificá-los **um a um**.

A configuração para isso resume-se a três opções:

#### 1. A estratégia `LinkerPleaseInclude` ou [FalseFlag](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker#falseflag)

Consiste em fazer uma referência para os membros e/ou classes que foram descartados.

Um exemplo da própria documentação da microsoft:

> ```
> [Activity (Label="Linker Example", MainLauncher=true)]
> class MyActivity 
> {   
>     static bool falseflag = false;
>     static MyActivity ()
>     {
>         if (falseflag)
>             var ignore = new Example ();
>     }
>     // ...
> }
> ```

Na prática esse código nunca será executado, mas como força uam referência para o tipo `Example`, esse construtor não será removido pelo Linker.

#### 2. Atributo [*Preserve*](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker#preserving-code)

Outra maneira de fazer o mesmo mostrado acima seria usar o atributo `Preserve`:

> ```
> public class Example
> {
>     [Android.Runtime.Preserve]
>     public Example ()
>     {
>         // ...
>     }
> }
> ```

#### 3. [Arquivo de configuração personalizado](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/linker)

A outra alternativa seria usar um arquivo xml com a configuração. Esse arquivo precisa ter sua ação de build definida como `LinkDescription`.

Eis um exemplo do arquivo da mesma fonte:

> ```
> <linker>
>         <assembly fullname="mscorlib">
>                 <type fullname="System.Environment">
>                         <field name="mono_corlib_version" />
>                         <method name="get_StackTrace" />
>                 </type>
>         </assembly>
>         <assembly fullname="My.Own.Assembly">
>                 <type fullname="Foo" preserve="fields">
>                         <method name=".ctor" />
>                 </type>
>                 <type fullname="Bar">
>                         <method signature="System.Void .ctor(System.String)" />
>                         <field signature="System.String _blah" />
>                 </type>
>                 <namespace fullname="My.Own.Namespace" />
>                 <type fullname="My.Other*" />
>         </assembly>
> </linker>
> ```

Esta última, entretanto, exige um aprofundamento maior no estudo do formato do arquivo esperado, sintaxe, caracteres coringa e por aí vai.

### E para identificar os membros, tipos e classes que foram removidas?

Essa é a parte difícil. Quando o projeto já está desenvolvido essa etapa deve consumir um tempo considerável. Para executála, você pode ativar o linker em modo debug, e ir colocando breakpoints na cadeia de execução do aplicativo e vai tratando caso a caso. Tem também a possibilidade de usar o [`BitDiffer`](https://github.com/bitdiffer/bitdiffer), comparando uma compilação sem e uma com o linker. Assim você vai conseguir identificar todos membros, tipos e bibliotecas que foram removidos e tratar diretamente os casos.

Detalhes nesse procedimento seria mais um tutorial e eu não acredito que seria um conteúdo *on* aqui no SOpt. Novamente recomendo o conteúdo do Módulo 8 da [Maratona Xamarin Avançada](https://cursos.bsgrupo.com/courses/course-v1:Microsoft+XMRBR101+2018_T1/about) que trata desse assunto.

### Finalmente...

Não dá para ajudar no seu caso específico, como você pode imaginar, pois em se tratando de Linker, cada caso é um caso. A sua solução precisa ser avaliada juntamente com a mensagem de erro do processo de linker ou de execução para irmos corrigindo.

Espero que isso ajude.

Comment: Olá Diego, obrigado por responder, eu retirei algumas bibliotecas do meu projeto que acredito terem sido as responsáveis pelo não arquivamento do meu projeto (no meu caso em especifico eram Xamarin.Theme.Base, Xamarin.Theme.Ligth, Xamarin.Theme.Dark ), ajustei o projeto e selecionei a opção de vincular "Somente Assemblies de SDK" ele conseguiu arquivar, gerou o apk e para minha surpresa o tamanho não foi reduzido em nada, continua um arquivo de tamanho gigante para um apk. Enfim, isso já problema para um outro tópico e estou pesquisando mais sobre o assunto. Agradeço novamente sua ajuda.

Comment: @Q.Wesley se o linker não fez diferença no tamanho do apk, temos duas opções: ou alguma biblioteca que vocÊ está utilizando é muito grande ou praticamente todo o conteúdo do app está sendo preservado e o linker não está tendo efeito. [Um projeto _hello world_ simples já teria uma redução de 70 a 87%](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker) no tamanho do apk. Dá uma conferida no BitDiffer

Comment: Oi Diego, obrigado pela ajuda, eu consegui gerar um apk com 15mb (já foi uma diferença tremenda), consegui isso refazendo todo o projeto, iniciei um projeto novo atualizei tudo, todas as bibliotecas, arquivos, importei as classes do meu projeto habilitei as opções e funcionou, não sei exatamente o que estava errado, mas funcionou. Não vou deixar de olhar o BitDiffer que você indicou, é uma ferramenta que com toda certeza vai me ajudar muito. Obrigado novamente.

Comment: Show de bola. 15 mb já torna as coisas mais fáceis. =)