# Tamanho de um aplicativo Xamarin Forms muito grande

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms, deploy

Criei a pouco tempo um aplicativo utilizando o Xamarin.Forms, porém apos realizar o lançamento o mesmo ficou com um tamanho de 15MB. Meu aplicativo possui um total de 8 paginas (*views*) dentre as quais apenas duas utilizam imagens e falando em imagens o tamanho total da minha pasta de *resoucers* não passa de 2MB.

É normal para um aplicativo feito em Xamarin?

No caso eu já deixei o *linker* ativo quando fui publicar, isso ajudou demais na redução do tamanho, mas ainda assim em comparação a outros aplicativos da própria Google Play vejo que o tamanho do meu aplicativo poderia ser menor.

Obs: Gostaria de deixar claro que já fiz um outro tópico onde peço dicas para reduzir o tamanho do meu aplicativo, onde obtive respostas e estou seguindo as dicas de lá ([Redução do tamanho do aplicativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/309560/falha-ao-arquivar-projeto-xamarin-forms)). A dúvida deste tópico é se é normal um aplicativo desenvolvido em Xamarin sem tantas imagens ficar deste tamanho atual (15MB).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, totalmente normal, está até pequeno porque usou técnicas para tirar boa parte do excesso não tão necessário. Ele precisa mandar todo o Mono necessário, todo o Xamarin, todo o Xamarin Forms além da sua aplicação que deve ser uma pequena porcentagem disto (nem tanto por causa de tantos *resources*, achei exagerado, mas pode fazer sentido).

Infelizmente em mobile o *deploy* é ruim assim mesmo. Acham que estão facilitando, mas em um dispositivo que precisa de economia mais que o desktop eles não permitem economizar como é possível no desktop. Mobile é uma plataforma muito errada que só deveria ser usada em último caso.

Se parar de usar o Forms o tamanho fica menor, se deixar de usar o Xamarin fica menor ainda. Mas talvez possa conseguir reduzir mais com as técnicas que já te falaram e outras parecidas.

Isso está sendo melhorado em cada versão e partindo do .NET 6 já começa ficar bem interessante, mas ainda não faz milagres.

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta, fico mais aliviado de saber que é normal esse tamanho de aplicativo criado no Xamarin. Vou dar uma olhada na pasta de resources para ver se consigo tirar uma coisa ou outra e seguir a dica de desenvolver em plataformas nativas para não ter problemas com tamanho. Muito obrigado novamente.